# Meaning of infimum of exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to show that if $\{E_i:i\in I\}$ are independent exponential random variables with parameters $\lambda_i$, then $\inf_{i\in I}{E_i}$ is also exponentially distributed.

But I am not really sure what is meant by $\inf_{i\in I}{E_i}$, because wouldn't all exponential random variables have infimum $0$?

Can someone also give me a hint for the question and finding such distribution?

Comment: Use `$\in$` for $\in$.

Comment: All the $E_i$-s are maps $\Omega\to \Bbb R$, and $\inf_{i\in I}E_i:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ is the map $$\left(\inf_{i\in I}E_i\right)(\omega)=\inf_{i\in I}E_i(\omega)$$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulioThanks!

Comment: For this question to be meaningful you need to specify the joint distribution. Are the $E_i$ independent?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, they are, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i<\infty$ (necessarily implying that $I$ is finite or countably infinite), then for any $t>0$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(E>t) &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i\in I} E_i>t\right)\\
&= \bigcap_{i\in I}\mathbb P(E_i>t)\\
&= \prod_{i\in I}\mathbb P(E_i>t)\\
&= \prod_{i\in I} e^{-\lambda_i t},
\end{align}
so that $E:=\inf_{i\in I}E_i\sim\mathsf{Expo}(\prod_{i\in I}\lambda_i)$. If the sum of the $\lambda_i$ does not converge, then $E=0$ with probability $1$.